# DCOM Object Reference C#

Tags: c#, activex, dcom, object-reference

I am trying to add a reference of the remote computer in a local network (computer name or IP address) to a DCOM object. Just for example:
When I do the following it works on the local machine:

```
private void btnOpnDWSFT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DEWEsoft.IApp x = new
    DEWEsoft.App();
    x.Init();
    x.Width = 1000;
    x.Height = 800;
    x.Visible = true;
}
```

But where shall I add the reference to the Remote Machine? BTW: The DCOM server is running and is registered on the remote machine and I got it working in LabView somehow (with ActiveX ObjectRef) but I couldn't get it work in C#.
I would like to remote controll SW called DEWEsoft on a different Machine.

Thank you!